# Composition best practice with internal object instantiation

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

I am playing around with composition and had a question. Say I have a `Fruit` and `Apple` classes where `apple` is a passthrough to a fruit

```
public class Apple {
    Fruit fruit;
}
```

Fruit has a bunch of member fields such as `skin`, `color` etc. What is the best practice when we instantiate an `Apple` object? Should I construct the `fruit` object internally without exposing any indication that the Apple contains a Fruit object? i.e. when constructing the Apple object, I call `apple.setColor()` which sets the `fruit.setColor()` property internally. Or, should I construct the full `fruit` object and during the `apple` instantiation, pass in the `fruit` object fully constructed?

Comment: Why do you want a Fruit object in an Apple in the first place?

Comment: Its just a contrived example to just have some context around my question. Essentially boils down to: If i have an instance of another class in my outer class, is it best practice to configure it internally or externally

Comment: Internally is the way to go.

Comment: So, for ex. in my Apple class, my setter for color apple.setColor(Color red) would essentially set fruit.setColor(red) and my getter for color in the Apple class apple.getColor() would return fruit.getColor()?

Comment: My previous comment is not accurate. In designing your Apple class, passing the entire Fruit to Apple through Apple constructor should be the better way. Unless you want your Apple to change color, setter is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how you are modeling your problem. But I think paying attention to *encapsulation* principle of OOP would help us. Encapsulation wants us to hide information about an object within itself, or, in other words give each object responsibility of performing its own actions.

Back to your question, first let us consider the case in which `Fruit` object is only an underlying data structure (i.e. `Apple` object is a complete superset of `Fruit` in responsibilities). In this case, if you ask  developers to construct the `Fruit` object for you and pass it along, you are exposing your internal responsibilities, and you may let the developer access to unwanted data or behavior.

```
Fruit f = new Fruit();
f.doSomethingPrivate(); // This is not intended for an Apple to be set externally

Apple a = new Apple(f); // Now the Fruit object may not comply with Apple definition
```

It is now obvious that in some cases, the above example is exactly the thing you want to do. Consider now the composition pattern (see [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074564/learn-java/a-look-at-the-composite-design-pattern.html)). In composition you have a *container* which is not anticipated to encapsulate the responsibilities for its contained elements.

A very simple example can be a university course, in which some students enroll and has an instructor:

```
public class Course {
    private Person instructor;
    private Person[] students;
}
```

Here, it is not the `Course` object responsibility to expose instructor or students behaviors. Instead, the container object may have `getInstructor()` and `setInstructor()` methods and let the developer decide about the contained elements in the composition.

Answer (score 0):

Seems weird to  have a Fruit inside an Apple. I would use inheritance in this  case. Or at least have Apple implement a Fruit interface and hide the delegate member. So for constructing the Fruit member, that means: Do it internally inside the Apple constructor. This is because of the is-a relationship between the Apple and Fruit concepts.

In other cases it might be usefull to pass a pre constructed instance for the member in the constructor. That would be the case e.g. if more apples refer to the same fruit instance. In general that would be more of a has-a or uses relation between Apple and Fruit

Comment: Got the idea from here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html